# Extrnal API access. Status_code 414

Tags: api

I am progressing deeper and deeper into CivCRM intricacies, and work with External (https://) access of the database via API's. When performing a python
requests.get(....,entity=Contact,action=get) it works OK, and I get the data I request.

Next I tried to update the contact/membership with a payment via
requests.get(...entity=Contribution, action=create...) and the same for requests.post, both gave the same disappointing  status_code of 414. I also tried to get some more information and among the plethora of data dumped the following was "readable":

*"is_error":1,"error_message":"API permission check failed for Contribution/create call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM and access CiviContribute and edit contributions"},* as well as a status_code of 414 (unknown to me)

I have now updated my access-capabilities (granted all "Edit Capabilities: Custom) in the role table in WP (where our CiviCRM resides), so I shall have all the rights mentioned above. Still the same problem. We run API 3 at present, but I do not think that is the problem here.

So here I am asking for some guidance, please!

Claes

Answer (score 1):

You'll have an easier time modifying the permissions from within CiviCRM - **Administer menu >> Users and Permissions >> Permissions (Access Control)**.  When changing permissions from WP, you're usually dealing with machine names, not human-readable labels, so it can be hard to correlate error messages with the particular permission needed.

It sounds like your REST user still doesn't have the *Access CiviContribute* permission.

Comment: Thanks. I am an Administrator so I should basically have full access to everything. Stil I have met a total blocking here.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a command-line CURL operation that duplicates the error (with both the command and the error)?  If you do, please comment on this answer so I'll get a notification!

Comment: You may also want to ask in the ~dev channel on https://chat.civicrm.org.

Comment: Jon, I'm really sorry, but I don't really know how to do that. I am trying to make the access via a Python programme. I can provide you with the call that gives the answer above. I'll run it and post it here.

Comment: Jon, I have now succeeded to proceed a bit. It has been suggested on the Mattermost site that I used the wrong API access way. It should be via the WP- aAPI v3 wrapper, so I tried it. Wasn't successful, but I have done some curl accesses. Please see the results I got from a a v3 access effort:

Comment: Claess-MBP:~ claesrickeby$ curl https://mdl.medborgerligsamling.se/wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest?entity=Contact&action=getvalue&api_key=x&key=y&json={"return" : "street_address","id":6570} -v
[1] 91058
[2] 91059
[3] 91060
[4] 91061
[2]   Done                    action=getvalue
[3]-  Done                    api_key=x
[4]+  Done                    key=y
Claess-MBP:~ claesrickeby$ {"code":"rest_cannot_access","message":"No one can access the REST API.","data":{"status":401}}

Comment: I do not know if you can get any sense from the information. Seems to be. permission problem. I am an admin and also a special Role apiUser, with the whole set of accesses Granted.

Comment: @ClaesRickeby That's helpful.  The error you're seeing is a WP error, not a Civi error.  There's [this page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/401-error-on-form-submission-rest_cannot_access/) that mentions a plugin that causes this error.  Are you able to access the WP REST API for non-Civi data?

Comment: Perhaps this gives some progress. I have tried the WP APi wrapper for Civi, v3. I got the following response.:

raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '"https://mdl.medborgerligsamling.se/wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest?key=site_key&api_key=apiKey&id=1795"'

Does this provide any further help. i'am really at a loss when it comes to these items. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I do not know if I can reach the WP Rest API for nonCivi data. I should have Administrator rights for the civi system but don't really know if it is ok for me to access the WP level.

Comment: Jon, I have also worked a bit with curl so if that could help I could try to provide more info with your guidance.